# Oozie doesn't take care of acl

Tags: hadoop, acl, kerberos, oozie

On my hadoop cluser, I have designed an oozie workflow with the following property.

```
 <global>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                <value>myQueue</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>oozie.launcher.mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                <value>oozie-launcher</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>tez.queue.name</name>
                <value>myQueue</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>oozie.job.acl</name>
                <value>*</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>mapreduce.job.acl-modify-job</name>
                <value>*</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
```

My concern is with the property `oozie.job.acl` wich is supposed to provide an acl that allow everyone to kill my workflow.

But when I try to kill it with a different user than the one who submit it, oozie return an error E0508

```
oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -kill 0000000-151020102420689-oozie-oozi-W                             
Error: E0508 : E0508: User [user] not authorized for WF job [0000000-151020102420689-oozie-oozi-W]
```

Am I missing something in the configuration of my cluster ? I am using oozie 4.1.0.

Comment: Any chance that `oozie.service.AuthorizationService.default.group.as.acl` might override your ACL settings? Cf. http://qnalist.com/questions/4804291/does-oozie-have-acl-policy-for-workflows

Comment: Hi I already check and it is set as false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally manage to find the answer to my question by having a look at Oozie source code and will post the solution.

In fact Oozie doesn't recognize the wildcard '*', you need to pass the full acl with the following format `USER1,USER2,USER3` also it seems that the format `USER1,USER2 GROUP1,GROUP2` like presented in the bug [OOZIE-228](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-228) doesn't work because Oozie split the acl string based on `,` character. And to be sure it is handled properly, the `oozie.job.acl` need to be in the job.properties and not in the workflow.xml.

Hope this will save time to people having the same trouble has me.

Comment: Typo: that JIRA is `OOZIE-228`, not `128`  (and the link is correct BTW)

Answer (score 0):

For this, to perform any operation like kill/suspend etc. we need to generate the authenticating token for our user id. 
First, we need to clear the existing tokens from the file using below command and then perform suspend/kill etc. action on given workflow id:

```
rm .oozie-auth-token
```

From Apache Oozie docs:

> Once authentication is performed successfully the received
>   authentication token is cached in the user home directory in the
>   .oozie-auth-token file with owner-only permissions. Subsequent
>   requests reuse the cached token while valid.

For more details, the link of Apache Oozie docs (refer Authentication section): [Official Documentation](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/DG_CommandLineTool.html#Authentication)